# Print DOI when there is no page number with biblatex-phys

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-phys

I'm using BibLaTeX with the `phys` style for my bibliography. The `biblatex-phys` documentation states:

> Note that DOI values are printed for journal articles with no pages
>   given, even if the `doi` option is `false`.

This is exactly the behaviour I want: print the DOI only when it's needed. However, it doesn't appear to work:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=phys]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
Test. \cite{spaeth_circular_2019,jollans_explosive_2019}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives (bib file below)

[image: Result of code sample]

No DOI, no pages, on the first reference.

Adding the option `doi=true` gives the expected result (DOIs everywhere).

**How do I fix this to get the documented behaviour?**

The file `test.bib`:

```
@article{jollans_explosive_2019,
    title = {Explosive, oscillatory, and Leidenfrost boiling at the nanoscale},
    volume = {99},
    url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevE.99.063110},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.99.063110},
    pages = {063110},
    number = {6},
    journaltitle = {Physical Review E},
    shortjournal = {Phys. Rev. E},
    author = {Jollans, Thomas and Orrit, Michel},
    urldate = {2019-09-21},
    date = {2019-06-27},
}

@article{spaeth_circular_2019,
    title = {Circular Dichroism Measurement of Single Metal Nanoparticles Using Photothermal Imaging},
    issn = {1530-6984},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.nanolett.9b03853},
    doi = {10.1021/acs.nanolett.9b03853},
    journaltitle = {Nano Letters},
    shortjournal = {Nano Lett.},
    author = {Spaeth, Patrick and Adhikari, Subhasis and Le, Laurent and Jollans, Thomas and Pud, Sergii and Albrecht, Wiebke and Bauer, Thomas and Caldarola, Martín and Kuipers, L. and Orrit, Michel},
    urldate = {2019-12-03},
    date = {2019-12-02},
}
```

Comment: Looks like a mess-up on my part: I'll fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the present, add

```latex
\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {%
      \printfield{doi}%
      \clearfield{doi}%
    }%
    {%
      \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
        {}
        {\clearfield{doi}}%
    }%
}
```

after loading `biblatex`. I'll fix this later today in the release.